# Pseudo-code algorithm to converting a Unicode string into the normalized forms

Tags: unicode, pseudocode

What are the algorithms (ideally in pseudo-code) to convert a Unicode string into the [normalised forms](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/)?

[Unicode® Standard Annex #15 UNICODE NORMALIZATION FORMS](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) does not give a concrete algorithm which can be directly coded in a language of choice.

Comment: The description given [here](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Description_Norm) is insufficient?

Comment: The document above contains an additional link to the formal specification of the algorithm (paragraph 3.11 of [this document](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode13.0.0/ch03.pdf)).

Comment: Many libraries and languages include it. So you the sources. Or maybe you should just check and use an existing libraries. Unicode website (the technical website) should have a link to a "reference" implementation. -- Or you should ask what part you do not understand (or fails tests), and what did you did.